# "Error: The file name must end with .xml" When using FileArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been getting an error when using this code. I have been making a file manager and every time I try to run the app it just says "Error: The file name must end with .xml" Just that, nothing else. I have no idea what's going on but if anyone could help me out that would be great!

```
package com.recoded.fileexplorer;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

private Context c;
private int id;
private List<Item>items;

public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    c = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = objects;
}
public Item getItem(int i)
{
    return items.get(i);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }

           /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
    //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

    final Item o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null) {
        TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                   /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
        String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

        if(t1!=null)
            t1.setText(o.getName());
        if(t2!=null)
            t2.setText(o.getData());
        if(t3!=null)
            t3.setText(o.getDate());
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: `I have been getting an error when using this code.`. Are you sure? Then which line exactly? Remove all code for the image view for instance to find out.

Answer (score 1):

please check all your drawable,menu,colors,attrs and layouts and make sure any non xml file is there. if yes then delete it and recreate .xml file if required

Comment: clean and rebuild project